# What is the C# equivalent of Java's InputStreamReader and BufferedReader

Tags: c#, io

I'm trying to convert these lines into C#, but I'm struggling. Mainly with InputStreamReader and BufferedReader lines.

```java
private static void runPrompt() throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

    for (;;) { 
      System.out.print("> ");
      String line = reader.readLine();
      if (line == null) break;
      run(line);
    }
}

private static void run(String source) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);
    List<Token> tokens = scanner.scanTokens();

    // For now, just print the tokens.
    for (Token token : tokens) {
      System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of an `InputStreamReader` in C# is a [`System.IO.StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-6.0). There is - AFAIK - no direct equivalent to a `BufferedReader` in C#. There is `BufferedStream`, but that is for byte-oriented streams, not character-oriented. However, `StreamReader` itself can be configured with a buffer through one of its constructors (i.e. `StreamReader(Stream, Encoding, Boolean, Int32)`.

Another way to look at it is that a C# `StreamReader` combines the functionality of Java's `InputStreamReader` (conversion from byte-oriented to character-oriented) and `BufferedReader` (buffering, reading lines).

Comment: I will be doing an byte-oriented system so BufferedStream should be thank you very much